# Error: Inflater YoutubePalyerView

Tags: android, youtube

I am having the following problem:

I have two classes: in one case I receive a JSON url and in the other is my adapter. That's OK but when I try to to set the link_to_youtube field inside one of the YoutubePlayerView in my layout I run into the the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.pedro.masterwc, PID: 14736
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
      at com.example.pedro.masterwc.Adapters.VideoAdapter.getView(VideoAdapter.java:46)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2098)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:828)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:588)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:558)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:814)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at com.example.pedro.masterwc.Adapters.VideoAdapter.getView(VideoAdapter.java:46) 
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347) 
      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864) 
      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698) 
      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759) 
      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659) 
      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703) 
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557) 
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2098) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5903) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:828) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:588) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:558) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:814) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
      at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at com.example.pedro.masterwc.Adapters.VideoAdapter.getView(VideoAdapter.java:46) 
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347) 
      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864) 
      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698) 
      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759) 
      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659) 
      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703) 
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557) 
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) 
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) 
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689) 
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5048) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2098) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073) 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5903) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:828) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:588) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:558) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:814) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

My Activity:

```
/**
 * Created by pedro on 12/10/2016.
 */

public class Channel1 extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Videos> videosList;
    VideoAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rows);

        videosList = new ArrayList<Videos>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://www.masterwebchef.com.br/wsmwc/teste/get_videos_channel4.php");

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_v);
        adapter = new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.videos, videosList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), videosList.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        //metodo para a toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.voltar4);
        toolbar.setTitle("");

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });





    }

    //faz a conexao com a URL do Json
    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Channel1.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Por favor, aguarde...");
            dialog.setTitle("Conectando ao servidor");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }
        //Recebe os dados do Json
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("channel1");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Videos v = new Videos();

                        v.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
                        v.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                        v.setLink_to_youtube(object.getString("link_to_youtube"));
                        //v.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                        //v.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                        //v.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                        //v.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                        v.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                        videosList.add(v);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não foi possivel acessar o servidor...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }






}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Videos> {

    ArrayList<Videos> videoslist;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;


    public VideoAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Videos> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        videoslist = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
            holder.link_to_youtube = (YouTubePlayerView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(videoslist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(videoslist.get(position).getDescription());
        //holder.link_to_youtube.setText(videoslist.get(position).getLink_to_youtube());
        holder.link_to_youtube.initialize(youtube.API_KEY, (YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) VideoAdapter.this);
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView description;
        public YouTubePlayerView link_to_youtube;
    }


    private class youtube extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

        public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDveKkSzopPSk7ck4ZDbR9YGBe4Mm35DYY";


        private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
        public YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.teste);

            youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Houve um erro ao carregar o video!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                            boolean wasRestored) {

            youTubePlayer = player;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Video carregado com sucesso!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(String.valueOf(holder.link_to_youtube));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What can be causing this error? Here is an example of the screen at where I am setting my information:
[image]

Comment: Please translate into English.

Comment: Hello, I have the following problem:

I have two classes, I get a json url and the other is my adapter. Well, when I try to set the link_to_youtube field into a YouTubePlayerView in my layout I encounter the following error:

Comment: my Activity:public class Channel1 extends Activity {

Comment: my Adapter public class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Comment: The original post I mean (not just putting the translation into the comments).